# To start our application when user selects a file to share

Tags: android

I am developing an application to share files between two devices. My task is to pin my application to the 'share menu' or 'send via menu' so that my application get started when the user want to share it through my application.

If anybody knows how to resolve this please answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When someone chooses a Share Via option from an Android program, what is usually happening is an Intent is being fired with a particular action. Usually the Intent.createChooser() method is used with an Intent that is set to a particular Action.

If your Activity's Manifest includes the correct Intent Filter, then it will be one of the possible selections in the selector that appears.

The common convention is something like this:

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(SOME_ACTION_STRING);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(actionIntent, "Pick an App");

startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

For the above, if you wanted your application to be an option, you'd need this in your manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="SOME_ACTION_STRING" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: For completeness, the Action used generally is ACTION_SEND with a special attribute used to specify the type. For example, `<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>` can be used to geht images to be sent.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, the addition is appreciated.